# Airflow DAG optimization

Tags: airflow

I'm developing a DAGS structure for several clients

The DAGS are exactly the same for all clients, except for:

- A numerical value that changes according to the client ID
- Schedule interval.

Is there any way to reuse the code already made for the various DAGS. What would be the best approach here ?

Tanks,
M

Answer (score 1):

You can can create [dag dynamically](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#how-to-create-dags-dynamically).

```
def create_dag(dag_id):
    """
    A function returning a DAG object.
    """

    return DAG(dag_id)


for i in range(10):
    dag_id = f"foo_{i}"
    globals()[dag_id] = DAG(dag_id)

    # or better, call a function that returns a DAG object!
    other_dag_id = f"bar_{i}"
    globals()[other_dag_id] = create_dag(other_dag_id)
```

So in your case set the `client_id` as part of the `dag_id`.

A good tutorial can be found [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags).